# Group ID's Who Only Have Y's and No N's in the Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been racking my brains on this one.  What I am trying to do is create a list of companies who don't have an uncompleted call.  Here is the table data:

```
COMPLETED   |  OWNER_ID
Y           |  5
Y           |  5
Y           |  5
N           |  5
Y           |  6
Y           |  6
Y           |  6
```

So from the table above all I would want to display is ID 6 as all their calls are completed unlike ID 5 who has an uncompleted call (specified by an N).  So I would just want to list:

```
COMPANY ID'S WITH NO UNCOMPLETED CALLS
6
```

I've tried:

```
 SELECT COMPLETED FROM b_crm_act 
 WHERE COMPLETED = 'Y' AND COMPLETED NOT LIKE 'N' GROUP BY OWNER_ID
```

But this shows all the Y's even though 5's have a N in it.  I just want to show the OWNER_ID  with only Y's.

Cannot find the answer to this even though it seems pretty easy to do.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  OWNER_ID
FROM 
  b_crm_act
GROUP BY OWNER_ID
HAVING SUM(COMPLETED = 'N') = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT OWNER_ID FROM b_crm_act 
WHERE COMPLETED = 'Y' AND OWNER_ID NOT IN
(SELECT OWNER_ID FROM b_crm_act WHERE COMPLETED =  'N')
GROUP BY OWNER_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this by calculating the count of each OWNER_ID and the count of all Y's in each OWNER_ID and use the `HAVING` filter to match both counts

```
SELECT 
SUM(`COMPLETED` ='Y') ally,
COUNT(1) allids,
`OWNER_ID`
FROM`testt` GROUP BY `OWNER_ID`
HAVING ally =allids
```

sample output without `HAVING` filter

```
ally allids OWNER_ID
3    4        5
3    3        6
```

sample output with `HAVING` filter

```
ally allids OWNER_ID
3    3        6
```

**Edit**

### [**See fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce0c5/1)